# ¿Como puedo pasar todos los valores de una pila a un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Dispongo de una pila que almacena enteros, y quiero almacenar todos los enteros de esa pila en un ArrayList.

```
Stack<Integer> pila;

pila.add(1);
pila.add(3);

ArrayList<Integer> camino = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < pila.size(); i++) {
    camino.add(pila.pop());
}
```

Comment: Hola, sería de gran utilidad que pudieses complementar tu pregunta añadiendo un fragmento de tu código a fin de que cualquier miembro de esta comunidad pueda ayudarte. ¡Saludos!

Comment: ¡Hola! Siempre será más fácil mostrarnos tu código y lo que falla en él (log, output) que contarnos lo que pasa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estás usando `java.util.Stack` como pila, esta clase implementa `java.util.Collection`, que es una collección.

`java.util.ArrayList` tiene un constructor para Collections:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
}
```

Suponiendo que tienes una pila de enteros:

```
Stack<Integer> pila;
```

Para pasar todos los valores de esa pila a un ArrayList, puedes usar:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList(pila);
```